# CSS counter is zero when selector contains class name

Tags: css, css-counter

I'm trying to use css counter to create nested counter list items for lists with some html class name.
I started with sample from [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters#Using_counters).
All works good until I add `.nested-list` to selector `ol.nested-list>li:before`.

Here's my css and html.

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
}
ol>li:before {
  counter-increment: section;
}
ol.nested-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol.nested-list>li:before {
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}

<ol>
 <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry with subentries
        <ol>
          <li>Entry</li>
          <li>Entry</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol>
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[Also on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/het7w5qg/9/)

Comment: Can you add an image or axample of what you want to reach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increment the counter for each list item and not it's `::before` pseudo element.

The `::before` and `::after` elements do not exit without `content`. Since most of the list items don't have `content` for their `::before` elements, the element doesn't exist and the nested `section` counter is not incremented correctly.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
}

li {
  counter-increment: section;
}

ol.nested-list {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ol.nested-list>li:before {
  content: counters(section, ".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry with subentries
        <ol>
          <li>Entry</li>
          <li>Entry</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted. And also for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you want to achieve and why do you need a `.nested-list` class there. Any way, I put her two workaround that could solve your problem.

**First: Without any class**
This will add sequential numbering to all the list

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

Note: in your code you had `ol>li` but it is not necessary to add direct parenting because `<li>` can only exist inside inside your `<ol>` so I reduced your code.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry with subentries
        <ol>
          <li>Entry</li>
          <li>Entry</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

**Second: .nested-list Workarround**
You can "hide" all the `::before` content and "unhide" for the first level of `ol.nested-list` and if you remove the direct `>` parenting you can have this kind of list on all the child list inside `.nested-li`

```
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nested-list > li::before{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Example:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: section;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counters(section,".") " ";
  visibility: hidden;
}
.nested-list > li::before{
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry with subentries
        <ol>
          <li>Entry</li>
          <li>Entry</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Entry</li>
  <li>Entry with subentries
    <ol class="nested-list">
      <li>Entry</li>
      <li>Entry</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Note: For the use of `::before` and `::after` it is better to add two clon `::`